# What is causing this sound?

Tags: bottom-bracket, pedals, clicking

https://vimeo.com/270962821?utm_source=email&utm_medium=vimeo-cliptranscode-201504&utm_campaign=28749

Guys at the bike shop recommended a bottom bracket change would fix the problem however it didn't. Do I need to change the crankset? Click sounds only appears when I pedal with my right side between 12 to 3 o'clock angle.

Thanks!

Note: if I pedal only on my left pedal, there will be no clicking sound.

Comment: Borrow a another pair of pedals and check!

Comment: Note that you can't swap pedals left for right - the threads are opposite and attempting to do so will ruin the cranks.   Just avoiding problems.

Comment: However if you're on a budget, consider disassembling your right pedal, clean and inspect might show why its clicking.  If the bearings are all round, and there are no marks in the races then reassemble and lube.  The worst that could happen is they don't get any better and you still need to replace them.

Answer (score 4):

I think you kinda answered your own question. If the noise appears only when force applied to the right pedal, it's almost certainly that pedal. Especially as you changed the BB already.

Check for play between the pedal and the crank. Turn the pedal and see if you can feel a 'hitch' or click.

Most bikes shops have a pile of old pedals (especially cheap platforms that come with new higher end bikes that get swapped out for clipless pedals). Ask if they will swap out your pedals for a set that are know to work OK as a test. If the click goes away - bingo. I'd ask them for a bit if a deal on replacing the pedals as they mis-diagnosed the problem first time around.

Comment: +1 And in addition: Removing the pedal, applying bearing-paste to it, re-attash it. Did the trick for me. I couldn't feel any movement though. I think that's the stage before movement occurs and where further damage can be easily prevented.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above regarding removing and regreasing your pedals, the same can be said for the interface between the crank arm and crank axle. Remove your cranks and clean the interface splines on both the cranks and the axle. Then regrease the splines liberally and reassemble being sure to tighten to the correct torque. If that was the problem the cranks should now rotate without clicking even when under load.